# Object Tags and Asp

Tags: asp.net, html, flash

I have a master page that gets all its images from a table on a database, and I am trying to incorporate flash, for banners, but I can't quite seem to figure it out.
Right now there is a:

```
<asp:image id="headerimg" runat="server">
```

and that generates the appropriate img tag needed to show an image in html. Now I would like to know if there is any way where I can generate an object tag if a .swf file is present and populate the tag with width height and data and also not show the img tag.

Update__

I now have made a usercontrol that will create the object tag, but can someone please tell me if it is looking like I am doing it right..

```
IDataReader dr = DB.GetRS("SELECT HeaderGraphic,HeaderAlign, fWidth, fHeight, Flash FROM Store where CustomerID='" + Session["Customer"].ToString() + "'");
if(dr["Flash"] == 1)
{
HtmlGenericControl obj = new HtmlGenericControl("object");
obj.Attributes["width"] = dr["fWidth"];
obj.Attributes["height"] = dr["fHeight"];
obj.Attributes["data"] = dr["HeaderGraphic"];
this.Controls.Add(obj);
}
else
{
HtmlGenericControl image = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
img.Attributes["src"] = dr["HeaderGraphic"];
img.Attributes["align"] = dr["HeaderAlign"];
this.Controls.Add(image);
}
```

is this continuing to look right? and is there anything I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a user control that generates the required `<OBJECT />` html to display the swf file and then you can dynamically load these if there are swf file present?

Comment: I am somewhat following what you are saying, but I'm not 100% clear on it

Answer (score 1):

> is this looking right? and how do I get this into the html?

Yes it looks right. You can add it into your page this way:

```
this.Controls.Add(obj);
```

Hope it helps!

Hanlet

EDIT: I could recommend you to look into [Generic Handlers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) and see if you can somehow use it. Good luck!

Comment: do I need to add anything to the ascx file, or is it all driven by the ascx.cs file?

Comment: It's just one file. The purpose of these handlers is to serve whatever doctype you specify in the Response.ContentType property. That's why it is so flexible to serve any type of files.

Comment: Alright Thank you, its just when I look at the ascx source page it just seems so empty, I'm just about ready to test it, I just have to make some modifications to the table that it is getting all the info from